# optimize `vh-100` in responsive

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have 2 column in the page `col-lg-8` and `col-lg-4`. for `colo-lg-4` i want to be span all height of the page and i give it `vh-100`. But height in tablet and mobile is the same(too long). How can i fix that?
`<div class=" col-lg-4  vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center  align-items-center   auth-sidebar"> <img src="../assets/img/Authentication.svg" alt="Authenticate" class="h-75 w-75" /> </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of three ways:

1- Using "-webkit-fill-available"

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* mobile viewport bug fix */
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

2- CSS Media Queries

```
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    .foo {                           
        height: 1024px;                         
    }                       
}   
                                            
/* iPad with landscape orientation. */                       
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {                         
    .foo {                           
        height: 768px;                         
    }                       
}
                                               
/* iPhone 5 
You can also target devices with aspect ratio. */                       @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {                              
    .foo {                           
        height: 500px;                         
    }                       
}
```

3- Targeting innerHeight with Javascript

```
window.onresize = function() {
    document.body.height = window.innerHeight;
}
window.onresize(); // called to initially set the height.
```